# When is mandatory use the "--keep-newer-files" option for the tar command?

Tags: tar, options

About the `tar` command

#### Introduction

Having for example:

```
source
 numbers
  001.txt # with the 111 content
  002.txt # with the 222 content
  003.txt # with the 333 content
```

If is created the `numbers.tar.gz` file through the `tar -czf numbers.tar.gz numbers` command, therefore now we have:

```
source
 numbers.tar.gz
 numbers
  001.txt # with the 111 content
  002.txt # with the 222 content
  003.txt # with the 333 content
```

Consider if the `mv numbers.tar.gz target` command is executed, therefore we have:

```
target
 numbers.tar.gz
```

If the `tar -xzf numbers.tar.gz` command is executed therefore we have

```
target
 numbers.tar.gz
 numbers
  001.txt # with the 111 content
  002.txt # with the 222 content
  003.txt # with the 333 content
```

Therefore as general overview we have:

```
source
 numbers.tar.gz
 numbers
  001.txt # with the 111 content
  002.txt # with the 222 content
  003.txt # with the 333 content
target
 numbers.tar.gz
 numbers
  001.txt # with the 111 content
  002.txt # with the 222 content
  003.txt # with the 333 content
```

#### Overriding control

Lets assume the following simple update:

```
target
 numbers.tar.gz
 numbers
  001.txt # with the 111 content
  002.txt # with the 222222 content <--- updated
  003.txt # with the 333 content
```

If the `tar -xzf numbers.tar.gz` command at the `target` directory is executed therefore the `002.txt` file is **overridden**, so its 222222 content returns to 222. Until here I am ok.

To keep the new data safe or to avoid a no desired override can be used the `--keep-old-files` and `--skip-old-files` options, according with the [tar(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar), it indicates:

```
-k, --keep-old-files
don't replace existing files when extracting, treat them as errors
--skip-old-files
don't replace existing files when extracting, silently skip over them
```

Therefore for the execution of the two following commands:

```
tar --keep-old-files -xzf numbers.tar.gz
tar --skip-old-files -xzf numbers.tar.gz
```

happens the following:

- the former always shows the `tar: numbers/222.txt: Cannot open: File exists` error message and the data is kept safe (remains with 222222)
- the latter shows nothing - the exception is if the `v` option is used - it shows the `tar: numbers/222.txt: skipping existing file` message; and the data is kept safe (remains with 222222). Useful for script purposes.

Until here, all is fine.

After to do a research I found the `--keep-newer-files` option, and according again with the [tar(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar), it indicates:

```
--keep-newer-files
don't replace existing files that are newer than their archive copies
```

Therefore for the execution of the following command:

```
tar --keep-newer-files -xzf numbers.tar.gz
```

happens the following:

- appears the `tar: Current ‘numbers/222.txt’ is newer or same age` message and the data is kept safe (remains with 222222)

Practically this `--keep-newer-files` option does the same than `--skip-old-files` about to avoid overriding *but* showing a different message.

**Question**

- When is mandatory use the `--keep-newer-files` option for the `tar` command over the `--keep-old-files` and `--skip-old-files` options?

I want to know what is the specific scenario where this options is mandatory.

Comment: "Practically this --keep-newer-files option does the same than --skip-old-files" - no, it only skips files that are newer. `--skip-old-files` skips them irrespective of whether the existing file's modification date is newer than the one in the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--keep-newer-files` is useful if you want to keep changes made on the target *after* the source files were last modified, and replace anything older on the target with newer versions from the source.

To illustrate the difference between the two options, you need another piece of information, the timestamp of each file. Consider the following:

```
source
  numbers
    001.txt # timestamp t1, contents 1
    002.txt # timestamp t1, contents 222
    003.txt # timestamp t1, contents 333
```

Those files are copied to `target` preserving their timestamp.

```
source
  numbers
    001.txt # timestamp t1, contents 1
    002.txt # timestamp t1, contents 222
    003.txt # timestamp t1, contents 333
target
  numbers
    001.txt # timestamp t1, contents 1
    002.txt # timestamp t1, contents 222
    003.txt # timestamp t1, contents 333
```

Now you fix `001.txt` on the *source* (observe the `t2` part):

```
source
  numbers
    001.txt # timestamp t2, contents 111
    002.txt # timestamp t1, contents 222
    003.txt # timestamp t1, contents 333
target
  numbers
    001.txt # timestamp t1, contents 1
    002.txt # timestamp t1, contents 222
    003.txt # timestamp t1, contents 333
```

Someone also edits `002.txt` on the *target* (observe the `t3` part):

```
source
  numbers
    001.txt # timestamp t2, contents 111
    002.txt # timestamp t1, contents 222
    003.txt # timestamp t1, contents 333
target
  numbers
    001.txt # timestamp t1, contents 1
    002.txt # timestamp t3, contents 22222
    003.txt # timestamp t1, contents 333
```

You create a new archive, and extract it on the target:

- without any option, all files are extracted, so the target ends up with the same contents in `001.txt` and `002.txt` as on the source, losing the changes made to `002.txt` on the target;
- with `--keep-old-files`, `001.txt` and `002.txt` aren’t extracted, and the target is left with its outdated version of `001.txt`;
- with `--keep-newer-files`, `001.txt` is extracted and overwrites the existing target file, because the existing file is older than the file in the archive, but `002.txt` is not extracted, because the existing file is newer than the file in the archive.

Comment: Huge thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: When a file has or keeps the same timestamp, and therefore is not overridden, appears the `is newer or same age` message, it can be confuse, I think is better  `is same age`.